# plt.imshow() giving TypeError("Image data cannot be converted to float")

Tags: python, tensorflow, matplotlib

I am new to python. While trying to plot the image using the code below -

```
import tensorflow as tf;
import os, sys;
import skimage;
from skimage.color import rgb2gray
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt;
import random


def load_data(data_directory) :
    directories = [d for d in os.listdir(data_directory) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(data_directory,d))]

    labels =[]
    images =[]

    for d in directories:
        label_directory = os.path.join(data_directory,d)
        file_names = [os.path.join(label_directory, f)
                      for f in os.listdir(label_directory)
                      if f.endswith(".ppm")]
        for f in file_names:
            images.append(skimage.data)
            labels.append(int(d))
    return images, labels

ROOT_PATH = "C:/Users/Administrator/Downloads/"

train_data_directory= os.path.join(ROOT_PATH, "BelgiumTSC_Training/Training")
test_data_directory = os.path.join(ROOT_PATH, "BelgiumTSC_Testing/Testing")
images, labels = load_data(train_data_directory)
traffic_signs = [300, 2250, 3650, 4000]
for i in range(len(traffic_signs)):
    plt.subplot(1, 4, i+1)
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.imshow(images[traffic_signs[i]])
    plt.subplt_adjust(wspace=0.5)
    plt.show()
```

I am getting the below error -

```
raise TypeError("Image data cannot be converted to float")
```

TypeError: Image data cannot be converted to float

Can someone please explain where I am going wrong. I am following the tutorial from - https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/tensorflow-tutorial#tensors

Comment: can you give the image variable data type? and insight about images variable

Comment: Method `load_data` from which package?

Comment: I tried with same code which is in datacamp and i didnt face any error as such.
please check the length of your images variable `print(len(images))` might be images are not imported

Comment: I have added the method - load_data. Also when I tried to print the len(images) I am getting 4575.

Comment: please provide entire error message

Answer (score 0):

In your method `load_data` in row `images.append(skimage.data)` you don't actually load any image, you just append the python module `skimage.data` to images, and that's reason why it can not show anything, because your `images` don't conain any image.
You probably want `images.append(skimage.data.load(f))` instead.